# pyxero get LineItems on banktransactions

Tags: python, xero-api

I'm running pyxero and trying to get the reference and description from a bank transaction but am having trouble getting it.

I can run:

```
trans = xero.banktransactions.filter(BankAccount_Name="chosen_account")
```

Which gives me the transcations and details, however the reference and description are not present.

It also shows the LineItems are empty:

> 'LineItems': []

I also get the same if I try:

```
transaction = xero.banktransactions.filter(BankTransactionID=BankTransactionID)
```

Is there a way to get this information?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Need to use get instead of filter to get the LineItems:

```
transaction = xero.banktransactions.get(BankTransactionID)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the lineitem detail you either need to :

- retrieve a specific item by BankTransactionID (as @blountdj implies in their answer)

**OR**

- use Xero API's built-in paging in the request by passing 'page=xxx' as an optional parameter (which you might need to loop through multiple pages/requests if >100 transactions - which is likely).

  Refer Xero API reference re Bank Transaction [paging](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/banktransactions#Paging) here